# return document with latest subdocument only in mongodb aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I've got these Mongoose Schemas:

```
var Thread = new Schema({
    title: String, messages: [Message]
});
var Message = new Schema({
    date_added: Date, author: String, text: String
});
```

How do you return all Threads with their latest Message subdocument (limit 1) ?

Currently, I'm filtering the `Thread.find()` results on the server side but I'd like to move this operation in MongoDb using `aggregate()` for performance matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$unwind`, `$sort`, and `$group` to do this using something like:

```
Thread.aggregate([
    // Duplicate the docs, one per messages element.
    {$unwind: '$messages'}, 
    // Sort the pipeline to bring the most recent message to the front
    {$sort: {'messages.date_added': -1}}, 
    // Group by _id+title, taking the first (most recent) message per group
    {$group: {
        _id: { _id: '$_id', title: '$title' }, 
        message: {$first: '$messages'}
    }},
    // Reshape the document back into the original style
    {$project: {_id: '$_id._id', title: '$_id.title', message: 1}}
]);
```

Comment: How would you return even threads with no messages ? I couldn't find many examples about condtions (except your answers on stackoverflow)

Comment: @younes0 It would be better to ask that as a new question.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526763/aggregate-return-document-with-no-subdocument-or-with-latest-subdocument-only

Comment: Nicely done - a simple result like this well documented and detailed.