# Aggregate: return document with no subdocument OR with latest subdocument only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

*This is a more complex version of [the query in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497016/return-document-with-latest-subdocument-only-in-mongodb-aggregate)*

I've got these Mongoose Schemas:

```
var Thread = new Schema({
    title: String, messages: [Message]
});
var Message = new Schema({
    date_added: Date, author: String, text: String
});
```

How do you return all Threads with their latest `Message` subdocument (limit 1) and all Threads without any `Message` subdocuments as well?

Comment: you can just query for all documents that have no messages.  If there are no messages there is an empty array?   then find({messages:[]}) will do it.

Comment: that's what I'm doing : merging two results set: one with no messages, and the other one with messages. But there got to be proper solution, by proper solution, I mean: one db call, less server-side code.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with aggregation framework.  You can do it with MapReduce, but that's definitely going to be slower than two fast calls.

Comment: Okay I see. I should learn about mongodb query cost. thank you Asya