# I want a specific document and only the latest item in a subdocument (Mongodb / Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a model like this:

```
User:
{
  name: "test",
  phone: "1234567890",
  password: "test",
  email: "test@tester.com",
  tasks: {
    { task: "do this", timestamp: "2015-08-01" },
    { task: "then this", timestamp: "2015-08-05" },
    { task: "finally this", timestamp: "2015-08-07" }
  }
},
... (more users) ...
```

How can I get a specific user's details like name, email, and only 1 task the latest one?

```
User.find({phone: '1234567890', password: 'test'}, '_id name email tasks',   function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            res.json({result: false});
        res.json({result: !(user == null), object: user});
});
```

This returns all the tasks.

Comment: The "latest one" means what exactly? Are the tasks always ordered? Can you live with keeping them always orderred, and if so then by what? timestamp? This makes a difference to what your answer is. Also the "timestamp" is a string where it probably should be a date object.

Comment: Latest one is the task with the most current timestamp and it will be a date object.

Comment: Well what I asked also there was *"Are they always ordered"* and if they are not then you chose the wrong answer ( not that the other is suitable ). It depends on whether the "last" array item is **always** what you want. As if they are not always in date order it makes a difference. Which is why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [$slice (projection)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#slice-projection)

```
User.find({
  phone: '1234567890',
  password: 'test'
}, {
    name: 1,
    email: 1,
    tasks: {$slice: -1}
}, function (err, user) {
   if (err) {
      res.json({result: false});
      return;
   }

    return res.json({result: !(user == null), object: user});
});
```

**Note** that `tasks` should be `Array` but not `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are inserting new task by push method of array. then you can get last record by getting length of tasks array and access last record by length - 1.

or you can refer this :
[return document with latest subdocument only in mongodb aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497016/return-document-with-latest-subdocument-only-in-mongodb-aggregate)