# How to find most recent subdocument in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose document called `RegisterList`, and that document contain sub-document called `Booking`.

Here i need to retrieve sub-document, which is most recently added sub-document

**below is my json Data**

```
[
    {
        _id: "56a3174bfc518cd014af7abd",
        area_name: "padi",
        name: "Vignesh",
        email: "vignesh4008@gmail.com",
        mobile_no: "9282438685",
        otp: "1625",
        __v: 0,
        date: "2016-01-23T06:01:47.450Z",
        booking: [
            {
                name: "Vignesh",
                mobile: "9282438685",
                can_name: "Kinley",
                can_quantity: "2",
                can_cost: "80",
                can_path: "http://test15.watervan.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/p-95-WV-Kinley-25l.png",
                delivery_date: "23-01-2016",
                delivery_timeslot: "3pm-8pm",
                order_id: "S16064",
                subscription: "true",
                subscription_type: "EveryDay",
                total_cost: "560",
                address: "12,Ramanrajan street,,padi,Chennai",
                _id: "56a3174bfc518cd014af7abe",
                delivered_at: "2016-01-22T18:30:00.000Z",
                ordered_at: "2016-01-23T06:01:47.451Z",
                status: "Delivered"
            },
            {
                name: "Vignesh",
                mobile: "9282438685",
                can_name: "Kinley",
                can_quantity: "2",
                can_cost: "80",
                can_path: "http://test15.watervan.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/p-95-WV-Kinley-25l.png",
                delivery_date: "24-01-2016",
                delivery_timeslot: "3pm-8pm",
                address: "12,Ramanrajan street,,padi,Chennai",
                order_id: "S16064",
                subscription_type: "EveryDay",
                _id: "56a31ba2d55894ec15eac1cf",
                ordered_at: "2016-01-23T06:20:18.479Z",
                status: "UnderProcess"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "56a0bc8d3306f388131e56c6",
        area_name: "kodambakkam",
        name: "Ganesh",
        email: "ganesh@gmail.com",
        mobile_no: "9042391491",
        otp: "7828",
        __v: 0,
        date: "2016-01-21T11:10:05.074Z",
        booking: [
            {
                name: "Ganesh",
                mobile: "9042391491",
                can_name: "Bisleri",
                can_quantity: "5",
                can_cost: "250",
                can_path: "http://test15.watervan.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/p-95-WV-Kinley-25l.png",
                delivery_date: "23-01-2016",
                delivery_timeslot: "3pm-8pm",
                order_id: "S12348",
                subscription: "true",
                subscription_type: "Alternate",
                total_cost: "1000",
                address: "15/A,Main Street,kodambakkam,Chennai",
                _id: "56a3164dc2c549e811c0d08f",
                delivered_at: "2016-01-22T18:30:00.000Z",
                ordered_at: "2016-01-23T05:57:33.169Z",
                status: "Delivered"
            },
            {
                name: "Ganesh",
                mobile: "9042391491",
                can_name: "Bisleri",
                can_quantity: "5",
                can_cost: "250",
                can_path: "http://test15.watervan.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/p-95-WV-Kinley-25l.png",
                delivery_date: "25-01-2016",
                delivery_timeslot: "3pm-8pm",
                address: "15/A,Main Street,kodambakkam,Chennai",
                order_id: "S12348",
                subscription_type: "Alternate",
                _id: "56a31c29d55894ec15eac1d0",
                ordered_at: "2016-01-23T06:22:33.307Z",
                status: "UnderProcess"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how can i find the most recent inserted sub-document alone. in the given JsonCode.

Help will be appreciated...

**Updated:**

I need to find data for the `AND` condition for `delivery_date` and `status`, so how can i write mongoose query to get data

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking. Do you mean the most recent `"ordered_at"` value from the array for each document in the collection? Or do you possibly mean the sub-document with the most recent value from **"all"** documents in the collection? At any rate, within any given document the "last" array item will always be the most recent unless you are specifically adding new items at positions or sorting the the arrays on update.

Comment: exactly **Do you mean the most recent "ordered_at" value from the array for each document in the collection**

Comment: If you push subdocument to `booking` array through `$push` operator, it inserts elements to the end of the array. Unless within [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) in it.

Comment: So the clarification we were looking for that makes the operation simple is if the "most recent" is always at the end of the array ( which it would be by default with no other modification ) then all you are really asking for is the "last" element of the array to be returned from each document. There is of course a built in "projection" operator for exactly that, and I'm also sure that direct question has already been asked here before.

Comment: you want the recent `ordered_at`, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497016/return-document-with-latest-subdocument-only-in-mongodb-aggregate?

Comment: I still don't really understand what you are trying to do: A) Do you have the full document loaded into memory already and want to find the most recent booking in it? -> then just use plain Javascript (or something like lodash) to find the right subdocument (or make sure your array is always ordered when you insert new orders and just get the last element) or B) do you want to query for the one document with the most recent order in it?

Comment: sorry, not enough info. Please write a full example of a query you would like to do in plain English and show us what you would expect as an answer. then we can help you write the query for mongoose.

Comment: @Reto This seems easy to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading OP's question correctly. Assuming he is asking for latest document in booking collection for each document, see my post below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on assumption, you can get latest sub document using aggregation framework.

> Mongodb Version 3.2+

```
db.col.aggregate([
{$project: {
    "area_name" : 1, 
    "name" : 1, 
    "email" : 1, 
    "mobile_no" :1, 
    "otp" : 1, 
    "__v" : 1, 
    "date" : 1, 
    "booking": {$slice :["$booking",-1]}}}
])
```

> MongoDB Version < 3.2

```
db.col.aggregate([
    // Stage 1
    {
      $unwind: "$booking"
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
      $sort: {
      "booking.ordered_at":-1
      }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
      $group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$_id",
        "area_name" : "$area_name", 
        "name" : "$name", 
        "email" : "$email", 
        "mobile_no" :"$mobile_no", 
        "otp" : "$opt", 
        "date" : "$date"   
        },
        booking:{$first: "$booking"}
      }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        _id: "$_id.id",
        "area_name" : "$_id.area_name", 
        "name" : "$_id.name", 
        "email" : "$_id.email", 
        "mobile_no" :"$_id.mobile_no", 
        "otp" : "$_id.opt", 
        "date" : "$_id.date",
        "booking": 1
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Based on your provided sample documents, output would look like

```
{ 
    "_id" : "56a3174bfc518cd014af7abd", 
    "booking" : {
        "name" : "Vignesh", 
        "mobile" : "9282438685", 
        "can_name" : "Kinley", 
        "can_quantity" : "2", 
        "can_cost" : "80", 
        "can_path" : "http://test15.watervan.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/p-95-WV-Kinley-25l.png", 
        "delivery_date" : "24-01-2016", 
        "delivery_timeslot" : "3pm-8pm", 
        "address" : "12,Ramanrajan street,,padi,Chennai", 
        "order_id" : "S16064", 
        "subscription_type" : "EveryDay", 
        "_id" : "56a31ba2d55894ec15eac1cf", 
        "ordered_at" : "2016-01-23T06:20:18.479Z", 
        "status" : "UnderProcess"
    }, 
    "area_name" : "padi", 
    "name" : "Vignesh", 
    "email" : "vignesh4008@gmail.com", 
    "mobile_no" : "9282438685", 
    "date" : "2016-01-23T06:01:47.450Z"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "56a0bc8d3306f388131e56c6", 
    "booking" : {
        "name" : "Ganesh", 
        "mobile" : "9042391491", 
        "can_name" : "Bisleri", 
        "can_quantity" : "5", 
        "can_cost" : "250", 
        "can_path" : "http://test15.watervan.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/p-95-WV-Kinley-25l.png", 
        "delivery_date" : "25-01-2016", 
        "delivery_timeslot" : "3pm-8pm", 
        "address" : "15/A,Main Street,kodambakkam,Chennai", 
        "order_id" : "S12348", 
        "subscription_type" : "Alternate", 
        "_id" : "56a31c29d55894ec15eac1d0", 
        "ordered_at" : "2016-01-23T06:22:33.307Z", 
        "status" : "UnderProcess"
    }, 
    "area_name" : "kodambakkam", 
    "name" : "Ganesh", 
    "email" : "ganesh@gmail.com", 
    "mobile_no" : "9042391491", 
    "date" : "2016-01-21T11:10:05.074Z"
}
```